# MSBuild Web service package deployment with separate web.config files

Tags: web-services, msbuild, msdeploy

We are trying to deploy a web service via MSbuild and then using MSDeploy to push the service to the IIS server. Based on the different environments we have separate config files that need to be referenced based on where they reside using  . The problem is when the package is created the other web..config files don't get package. I've tried using

```
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
 CustomCollectFiles;
 $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
 </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
```

Combined with

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
 <ItemGroup>
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="*.config">
     <DestinationRelativePath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
   <FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

But It doesn't seem to copy the files over. Am I doing something wrong or is my option to turn these in to Transform Files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I never tried just renaming the files... as long as the config file doesn't start with Web MSBuild copies the file into the package and doesn't assume that its a transformation file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. I'm using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.

You can call it from MSBuild script using Exec task.